# Gentoo Portage Circular Dependency

Tags: gentoo, portage

I installed a new Gentoo Linux on my box. I'm using Arch Linux for a while now and I thought it was time for something new.

The system runs happily and it is bootable, but I can't figure out how to break this circular dependency between glibc and gcc...

It says this:

```
(sys-libs/glibc-2.17::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) depends on
  (sys-devel/gcc-4.7.3-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) (build time)
    (sys-libs/glibc-2.17::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) (build time)
```

The funny is, I have a gcc of version `(Gentoo 4.7.3-r1 p1.4, pie-0.5.5) 4.7.3` installed.

What did I break during installation? Can I fix that?

EDIT
As requested here comes the info dump:

```
Portage 2.2.7 (default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/kde, gcc-4.7.3, unavailable, 3.10.25-gentoo x86_64)
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-3.10.25-gentoo-x86_64-Intel-R-_Core-TM-_i5-2450M_CPU_@_2.50GHz-with-gentoo-2.2
KiB Mem:     8096280 total,   7568704 free
KiB Swap:    8388604 total,   8388604 free
Timestamp of tree: Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:00:01 +0000
ld GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.23.2
Repositories: gentoo
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
FCFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles merge-sync news parallel-fetch preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync"
FFLAGS="-O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://linux.rz.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/download/gentoo-mirror/"
LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS="--jobs=5"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"
PORTDIR_OVERLAY=""
USE="X a52 aac acl acpi alsa amd64 berkdb bindist bluetooth branding bzip2 cairo cdda cdr cli consolekit cracklib crypt cups cxx dbus declarative dri dts dvd dvdr emboss encode exif fam firefox flac fortran gdbm gif gpm gtk iconv ipv6 jpeg kde kipi lcms ldap libnotify mad mmx mng modules mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib ncurses nls nptl ogg opengl openmp pam pango pcre pdf phonon plasma png policykit ppds qt3support qt4 readline sdl semantic-desktop session spell sse sse2 ssl startup-notification svg tcpd tiff truetype udev udisks unicode upower usb vorbis wxwidgets x264 xcb xcomposite xinerama xml xscreensaver xv xvid zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="kexi words flow plan sheets stage tables krita karbon braindump author" CAMERAS="ptp2" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="keyboard mouse evdev" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-5" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python2_7" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_3" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby19 ruby18" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="fbdev glint intel mach64 mga nouveau nv r128 radeon savage sis tdfx trident vesa via vmware dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS, SYNC, USE_PYTHON
```

Comment: Please, include output of `emerge --info` to your question.

Comment: @Nikolay I added the information you requested for.

Comment: Ok. There is [advice](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-6140832.html#6140832) on Gentoo forum how to go around this circular dependency. Briefly: you will enforce installation of `gcc` without dependencies (as said on forum it should be safe, because `gcc` is [sloted](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1#doc_chap5)) and after that you will install `glibc`.

Comment: @Nikolay GCC is building at the moment, thanks a lot.

Comment: Good. So, I put this as answer to "close" the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [advice](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-6140832.html#6140832) on Gentoo forum how to go around this circular dependency.

Briefly: you will enforce installation of `gcc` without dependencies (as said on forum it should be safe, because `gcc` is [sloted](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/slotting/)):

```
emerge --nodeps gcc

gcc-config YOUR_VERSION_HERE
```

and after that you will install `glibc` and `gcc` again:

```
emerge glibc && emerge gcc
```

Version of `gcc` for `gcc-config` can be obtained with `gcc-config -l`

Comment: BTW, I found out why these cyclic dependencies occured whilst the binaries were on my system. I managed to kill my /var partition during installation...

Comment: Wow. Well, welcome to Gentoo Linux!